# How to put a View into Bundle

Tags: java, android, bundle

I'm adding dynamically created EditTexts to a layout (onClick button method). When I rotate the screen the added edittexts disappear. How can I add them to a bundle to put them in the onSavedInstanceState method? Or, is there another way to do this? I know I can save the text, but is there a way to keep the screen layout when I rotate it? If the user presses the button and adds five EditTexts(with or without typing anything) I need to save this layout when the screen is rotated (I basically need to dummy-proof my app :) ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I got it! I'll save the strings from the edittexts to the bundle, and then populate new edittexts when the screen rotates. You guys jared my memory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot add views to a bundle because they are not parcelable / serializable. The only stuff you can and should save into the bundle is the current state of the activity.

You could maintain a list data structure or a counter variable that keeps track of the dynamically created views. Also save the string values of the EditTexts. In onCreate you should interpret that information in order to recreate the views and their states.

Comment: How would I create the counter variable? I don't have an onClick listener; I have an onClick method in my xml file. Could I save the strings to an array, and then use a for loop to create the edittexts and add the strings by indexing through the array elements?

Comment: Since Google recommends the use of code compression and obfuscation via ProGuard you should not define event handlers in XML (unless you protect the method names in the ProGuard configuration file). Set / create the onClick event handlers in your code. I do not exactly know how you are creating these EditTexts. If they don't have some fancy positioning applied, then you really just need to save their text values and iterate over that string array list from the savedInstanceState bundle in onCreate in order to re-create these EditTexts.

Answer (score 2):

you can't save a view. bundle is just a pair name-value. of course you can save the text and then render it again. the way is just you said.

onsaveInsatnceState(bundle save) save the text as  save.putString('text1','bla bla') of course you need a loop to save all your edittext.

then in oncreated( bundle save)

you can get what you have added by save.getString('text1')

Comment: I know I can save the text, but is there a way to keep the screen layout when I rotate it? If the user presses the button and adds five EditTexts(with or without typing anything) I need to save this layout when the screen is rotated (i basically need to dummy-proof my app :) ). Sorry if what i wanted wasn;t clear. Thanks!

Comment: don t worry. but unfortunatly you can t save views, you can save the number of editText and the text and compound the layout again using this information. I think it's the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Views itselfs doesn't represents information that you need to save. Instead you should save their coordinates, width, height, value etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your can save your view data into a class or into a arraylist. 
when your fragment activity will restart than you fetch data from saveinstance state in oncreate function.

Use this function setRetainInstance(true). after using thing function your fragment activity will not destroy.