# How to send an SearchView Object within Bundle to Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, searchview

I have an SearchView object. I want to send to Fragment (`MyFragment.java`) from `MainActivity`.

I am using `setArguments()` method. But, I couldn't put `searchView` object to bundle.

This is my code.

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("searcObject",searchView);

MyFragment f1 = new MyFragment();

f1.setArguments(bundle);
trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f1).commit();
```

Comment: do you really think,that what you are doing is possible??

Comment: i dont know that is possible or impossible.. i am here to learn that.

Comment: If that's the case then it's not possible you can't send view object from one activity to another by any means. You can only set values related to that view like text, position etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as views are not parcelable / serializable. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193675/how-to-put-a-view-into-bundle) question for a full explanation

Comment: hmm.. thanks bro. i understood. 
well,is there any way to send an view object to fragment?

Comment: You could pass the view into the fragment through the constructor or use a setter method. If you want to interact with the view from the fragment you would be better implementing a passback interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass searchView.getQuery().toString() data to bundle and get this String in your fragment

```
searchView.getQuery() // will return data
```

Then you can set this data again in your fragment searchView whit

```
searchView.setQuery(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to send is the query inside the Searchview.

So this is how you should do it

```
    String query = yourSearchView.getQuery().toString();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("searcObject",query);
```

Comment: i dont want to send a String..
i want to send an object.